Reference request: Poincare Theta Series' convergence (analytic/algebraic proof)
I am trying to find a proof of the convergence of the Poincare-$\theta$ series absolutely and uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.
The approach in Ford's 'Automorphic functions' is somewhat geometric (calculating the series as a sum of areas of disks that converges). Are there references where I can get a completely analytic or algebraic proof of this convergence?
By Poincare-$\theta$ series I mean the same series as in page 103 of Ford's book, which is $$\theta_q(z) := \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (c_i z+d_i)^{-2q} H(z_i),$$
where $z_i=T_i(z) = \frac{a_i z+ b_i}{c_i z+ d_i}$, $a_id_i-b_ic_i=1$, $H$ is a meromorphic function whose poles are at limit points of the group, $q \geq 2$ in general or $\geq 1$ for Fuchsian groups of second kind.

What does a Poincare $\theta$ series mean to you?

Thanks for asking. I have updated the information in the post above.
